# Javascript parseInt on large negative number gives NaN

Tags: javascript, nan

When I do this:

```
var x = parseInt("–2147483648");
console.log(x);
```

I get the value as:

```
NaN
```

Why does this happen?

I want to test if a number is in the range of C (int), so I am doing the above, but it does not work. Also, I want to do this for C (long), is there a way to this?

For example:
If I do:

```
var x = parseInt("-9223372036854775808");
console.log(x);
```

Now, I know that (-+)2^53 is the limit of numbers in Javascript. Is there some other way to test if the given value in a form is actually in the range of long or int?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It should work fine, the problem is that you're using the wrong character, an ndash `–` vs a hyphen `-`:

```
var x = parseInt("-2147483648");
console.log(x);
```

If you copy/paste that you'll see that it works now.

Comment: +1 Good catch. I was starting to think it had something to do with `If the first character cannot be converted to a number, parseInt returns NaN.` from [Mozilla's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). Apparently whoever wrote that needs more coffee too.

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days of trying various approaches, this solved my problem.
The numeric picker was using wrong negative format. I changed the field to textstring and then with parseInt I got correct negative numbers.