# Checking negative values from Google Forms

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

What I'm trying to achieve here is to check if the value submitted from my form meets certain criteria, and then send a mail. When the value meets the positive criteria I recieve the mail(so the mail part isn't the issue.

```js
if(parseInt(e.values[2]) > -15)  
  {  
    mailInnhold +="Fryser 200 er registrert som " + e.values[2] + " grader. " + "\n";
    feil++;

  }


 if(parseInt(e.values[3]) > 4 || parseInt(e.values[3]) < (-1))  // Kjøl 102 //
  {  
    mailInnhold += "Kjøl 102 er registrert som " + e.values[3] + " grader. " + "\n";
    feil++;

  }
```

When I try to do parseInt() on negative values, I get NaN. Apparently this is because I'm receiving an ndash – instead of a hyphen - from the Form, but I'm not able to fix this and I'm not finding anything relevant on Google either.

I'd greatly appreciate any help , and if there's any issues with my question then I'll happily remove it if that's wished for(given sufficient reasoning).

EDIT: The question I'm referring to is: [Javascript parseInt on large negative number gives NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825781/javascript-parseint-on-large-negative-number-gives-nan)

EDIT2: MVCE and sample for Rubén

```
function emailNotification(e) { 
  Logger.log(e.values[1]); //Where e.values[1] is entered as -1 in the form
  Logger.log(parseInt(e.values[1]));


}
```

Running this returns:

[16-12-29 12:44:03:822 CET] −1
[16-12-29 12:44:03:823 CET] NaN

Comment: if indeed users are typing that character, check for it in the code and replace with dash before the parse.

Comment: @ZigMandel, for now I'm the only one who writes data into the form, and I've been explicitly using ' - ' and not ' – ', but Google Forms submits  – through e.values

Comment: Please add sample data input as well a [mvce].

Comment: I just ended up going what @ZigMandel suggested, I check all submitted data for ' – ' and replace() it with ' - '. I'd still really like to know why this happens as I am only using ' - ' when I enter negative values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think "-" can be use to indicate negative numbers. As you can see in my code below parseInt() was able to convert the string "-2" to int and worked as expected when compared to the value 1. So this is not Apps Script's fault.

```
function myFunction() {
  var str = "-2";
  if(parseInt(str) > 1){
    Logger.log("True");
  }else{  Logger.log("False");} //Output is False.
}
```

Kindly check the value of `e.values[2]`  first in the console.log() before it reaches this line

```
if(parseInt(e.values[2]) > -15)
```

Comment: –2, not -2. I ended up fixing this through replace() as I couldn't think of any other way to do it.

Comment: @DoehringCowart smart thinking :)